# User Is Not Logged In using Multi Auth/Guard in Spatie

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

i'm try to using multi auth using Admin Guard and implement with Spatie, after login succes using the Admin Guard, then access the Group Middleware but i got an error 403 USER IS NOT LOGGED IN.

this is my code :

**Admin Model :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
    
class Administration extends Authenticable 
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;

    protected $guard_name = 'admins';


    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'photo'
    ];

    protected $hidden = ['password'];
}
```

**LoginController :**

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admins')->except('logout');
    }

    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {

        if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
            return redirect()->route('bank.master-bank.index');
        } else if ($user->hasRole('finance')) {
            return redirect()->route('bank.master-bank.index');
        } else if ($user->hasRole('supervisor')) {
            return redirect()->route('bank.master-bank.index');
        }

        return redirect('login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (auth()->guard('admins')->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
            return redirect()->intended('/bank/master-bank');
        } else {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors(["Incorrect user login details!"]);
        }
}
```

**Auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Administration::class,
        ],

    ],
```

**Route Web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admins'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {
            Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'as' => 'user.'], function () {
                Route::get('/', [UserAdminController::class, 'user_panel'])->name('user_panel');
                Route::get('/role-user', [UserAdminController::class, 'role_panel'])
                Route::get('/detail_user/{id}', [UserAdminController::class, 'detail_user'])
    
                Route::resource('/verif-user', VerifUserController::class);
            });
        });
});
```

when access the **Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function () {** i got error **403
USER IS NOT LOGGED IN.**

Comment: Use this way `role:Super Site Admin,user` user is guard name defined in auth

Comment: `$router->group(['middleware'=>['role:Super Site Admin|Super Merchant Admin,user'] ],function() use($router){
    //
});`

Answer (score 0):

Check you haven't define your middleware **role** and you are using it here.

Comment: i got a problem, when i chage the default guard into the admins guard, i can solved that spatie login problem, but here i have an api guard to, so when i change the default guard into admins the API auth can't use, is there way to change the guard of spatie ?